# How to store the value of a button on click event in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of buttons that I've created:

```
<button> red </button>
<button> blue </button>
<button> yellow </button>
```

How can I store the value of what has been clicked (let's say I click Red), into my on click event so that I can use the value within the function of my on click event?

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var colour = "red";
  alert("You have chosen " + colour);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('button').on('click', function() {

  // $(this) gives you the object where the click event occured

  alert("You have chosen " + $(this).text().trim());
});
```

You can also use value attribute,

```
<button value="red"> red </button>
<button value="blue"> blue </button>
<button value="yellow"> yellow </button>

$('button').on('click', function() {

  alert("You have chosen "+$(this).text().trim()+" "+ $(this).val()+ " " + $(this).attr('value'));

});
```

Check the demo : [HERE](http://jsbin.com/toveboqeku/1/edit?html,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to get the text, as

```
$('button').on('click', function() {
    var colour = $.trim( $(this).html() );  
    alert("You have chosen " + colour);
});
```

Demo:: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a9o1ophq/)

Answer (score 0):

you can obatin the value from buttton with `html()` check the [jsfidle example](http://jsfiddle.net/e0mnuh7f/1/)